# Automate a different website via my website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web, automated-tests

First of all, sorry if I make mistakes in my English language.

I have a website on Linux Ubuntu, I just want to automate different website, but users can see whats automate on different in browser's second tab. The exaple scenario is ;

User click a button in my website. This click is open a second tab in browser to -for example- google.com, write someting and click to search button automatically. User do not anything excluding click button in my website.

I am search a lot of thing on the internet for that. There are Selenium, puppeteer, Laravel Dock etc. But they for headless browser or just one user that having code on their pc. I want to everybody can do that which click button on my website.

How can I do that?

[SOLVED]

I found a way and looks like it is the only way. The way is Make a Chrome Extension for Google Chrome. I can make what I want for any website. Thanks.

Comment: While you can open a new tab which points to a specific site on your website that shows an animation (like lmgtfy's animation), it's impossible to interact with a different site without installing something on the user's computer.

Comment: If that's acceptable, you'll have to find some way to mirror selenium's page content on user's browser side (it's not easy -- even too broad for one question on this site, but possible. There are remote browsers like puffin that does it)

Answer (score 0):

This is cross-website communication which can be done in two ways.

1. Query Parameter, you can send the query parameters to another website via query. e.g. https://www.google.com/search?q=stack+overflow
2. Use the APIs, for this you need to create API and consume it for communication which is a complex but secure solution.

Thanks

Comment: I thougt that two methods but I can not use their. Because of, that is a progressive period. For example, click the button will opening a different page, fill the form and click the button and again fill the different form and click the button etc. For the second solution, there is no API for the I want to go website. So I can not use that solution.

Comment: What i understand, in this case, you can follow the technique of Request ID. It means that once clicked on button, a form id will be generated with stage id. So you go to any stage, base on request id, populate the data from backend.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want the "different website" tab to be interactable and accept user input?
In case you don't, you can execute selenium test on the backend, record a video of a test case and stream it to your client.

Comment: Yes, client will do interact different website. Actually, I have client's unregulated data, I edit that on my own and fill the form on different website, user checks and confirm it. So, yes client will do interact.